# Doesn't wrap_content adjust to the size of fonts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

My understanding was that the wrap_content take as much space as needed by its contents. But doesn’t this apply to TextViews as well?

In the following layout why when I change the font of TextView with id real_status to 24 the text is partially hidden? I was expecting that due to the wrap content the enclosing TextView it would wrap around the 24 sp and display the text fine. It is fine with 18sp.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/real_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/full_display_name"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/full_display_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Active"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/full_display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/real_status"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="The real user status:"
            android:textSize="16sp"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/full_display_name"
            android:gravity="right"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:text="Just a text view"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With 18sp: [image]

With 24sp: [image]

**UPDATE:**
Following the answers I removed the layout top/bottom and the font adjusted but now I see that the TextView overlaps with the next widget. Adding red background is more visible.
I thought that by “growning” the TextView the rest would move down and not overlap
[image]

Comment: `RelativeLayout` rules trump size values, particularly when you pin both ends of an axis. You are pinning the top and the bottom of `real_status`, and so `real_status` will be that height, not `wrap_content`.

Comment: @CommonsWare:Please see update in OP

Comment: "I thought that by “growning” the TextView the rest would move down and not overlap" -- you are not using `LinearLayout`, where size moves widgets. You are using `RelativeLayout`, which, unlike `LinearLayout`, is happy to have widgets overlap on the Z axis. If you want `full_display_name` to be below `real_status`, have `android:layout_below="@id/real_status` on `full_display_name`.

Comment: @CommonsWare:Is there a way to “trick” this? I.e. add something? Or is not possible?

Comment: Is what "not possible"? Again, if you want the position of `full_display_name` depend upon the size of `real_status`, you need to set up the rules to match that.

Comment: @CommonsWare:I meant increase the font and the following vertically widgets move dps further down despite being nested in a RelativeLayout

Comment: "I meant increase the font and the following vertically widgets move dps further down despite being nested in a RelativeLayout" -- then set up your rules to reflect that. As I suggested, have `android:layout_below="@id/real_status` on `full_display_name`, so `full_display_name` moves down when `real_status` changes.

Answer (score 1):

whenever You suffering from this type of problem You can LiniarLayout is best if You understand it very well. because of wrap_content and match_parent is simple to handle in  LiniarLayout.

lets understand it.(For Your case)..
1.take two LiniarLayout(parent have verticle orientation..)
     i give Id LL1(horizontal) and id LL2 for your case

2.in first layout two textview **@+id/full_display_name** and **@+id/real_status**
      in real_status have match_parent in width so it easy to divide parent(fill_parent) and set its android:gravity="right"

3.LiniarLayout as it is without relate

See belove XML code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/full_display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The real user status:"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/real_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Active"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/real_status"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Just a text view" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will help you Your GUI give bestView in All devices with any size of text

***Hope it help You***

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `wrap_content` will take as much space needed by the view. It will also applied to the `TextView` also. The problem here is you written `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/full_display_name"` to real_status text view. This attribute is overriding the `wrap_content` So remove allignBottom attribute from the text view.

**UPDATE**
For your bottom linear layout update the line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/full_display_name"
```

with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/real_status"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two line will fix your problem

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/full_display_name"            
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/full_display_name"
```

Comment: Just a text vie should be below real_status ==>  android:layout_below="@+id/real_status